# Why does my self-hosted wordpress site take so much space?

Tags: wordpress, hosting, storage, woocommerce

I'm using a self-hosted wordpress site (shared host), my hosting plan allows 4GB, although I have lots of images, but in my computer it only takes up 260MB, but for some reason in my hosting CP, it shows 3GB of public_html and 500MB of mySQL, 400MB of logs.

I see for each image, it generates like 8 versions with different sizes which I don't really need all of them (but I do need 1 small thumbnail, one medium, and 1 large).

Even with those 8 extra versions (which in smaller sizes than the original images) - it shouldn't take that much space.

Is there anyway I can "fix" this problem? Or is there anyway to host these pictures somewhere else to lighten the load on my host? I contacted maxCDN support and they say they only keep "cache" of images already on my host, so I assume CDN is out of the question.

Please if you want to help, be very basic 'cause I'm very new to this stuffs.

My site is a online shop with 300-400 products which each product has 3-4 extra images.

Thank you so much for any suggestion, I'm very desperate right now.

Edit 1: Actually, wordpress/woocommerce actually makes 14 resizes of the every image that I uploads (even though I will only need 3 version for featured product image (1/5 of the images are featured product images) , only 2 versions for general product images (most the the pictures I uploaded are in this category). How do I: 1, delete the unnecessary images (tried DNUI Delete Unused Images plugin - but after scan, it listed ALL of my images as unused) 2, how to I stop wordpress/woocommerce from generating so many resizes of each picture I uploaded?

Here is an example (when I scan with DNUI plugin)
Mask-of-a-Thousand-Faces.png    View <--- original image, below images are not my uploads

Mask-of-a-Thousand-Faces-80x53.png    View

Mask-of-a-Thousand-Faces-300x199.png    View

Mask-of-a-Thousand-Faces-36x36.png    View

Mask-of-a-Thousand-Faces-70x50.png    View

Mask-of-a-Thousand-Faces-512x280.png    View

Mask-of-a-Thousand-Faces-495x340.png    View

Mask-of-a-Thousand-Faces-241x179.png    View

Mask-of-a-Thousand-Faces-446x218.png    View

Mask-of-a-Thousand-Faces-492x165.png    View

Mask-of-a-Thousand-Faces-512x151.png    View

Mask-of-a-Thousand-Faces-512x107.png    View

Mask-of-a-Thousand-Faces-130x85.png    View

Mask-of-a-Thousand-Faces-450x340.png    View

Mask-of-a-Thousand-Faces-450x298.png    View

Comment: Do you actually use cPanel or are you referring to a general control panel from your hosting company?

Comment: CP from my hosting company

Comment: Do you have the ability to use `SSH` or sometimes referred to as `Shell Access`?  This is probably located somewhere in your control panel if you have access.

Comment: Turned out the problem is obvious, I was being retarded, the 14 resizes for EACH image IS the problem I have, so I did these two things:

1, Go to wordpress dashboard / settings / media , turn those resize options to 0 x 0 (this will disable the resizing function thus no more unnessary image resizes)
2, Use DNUI Delete Unused Image plugin to delete all the resizes

Now I'm back to what I expect. Thank you for your time.

I also would like to close this question but I don't know how.

Comment: To close, add your previous comment, your solution, to the answer box.  Then click to accept your own answer.  Glad you got it worked out.  I'll add a quick answer for reference in case a crawler comes through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference:

If you have access to SSH / Shell Access, the following command will show which directories are consuming large disk space.

```
du -sh *
```

Documentation using cPanel: [shell access](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/ShellAccess)